# Trying to loop through lines on stdin

Tags: bash

I would like to make a short script that will eventually run a quiz.

I'm trying to read `stdin`, which contains a new-line delimited list of words, for example:

```
vestirse
lavarse
lavarse los dientes
ducharse 
bañarse
```

My program so far doesn't seem to be converting input into any type of iterable array:

```
read inputlines
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a y <<<"$inputlines"

for line in "${lines[@]}"
do
  echo "$line"
done
```

Now if I run `pbpaste | bash wordlearner.bash` nothing is printed at all, even though I am expecting (at this point) basically a perfect `echo` of what was input.

How do I store `stdin` to be looped through at a later date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a while loop, and then ask for input to read though `/dev/tty`?

```
while read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
  echo "What do you think?"
  read -r answer < /dev/tty
done
```

Alternative use `mapfile` to slurp all lines into an array?

```
mapfile -t lines
for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
  echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: I already had this solution previously, but it wasn't working because I also intend to take input from the user in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Yes that works really well. Thank you , didn't know about `/dev/tty`

Comment: `mapfile ... < /dev/stdin` is redundant; it *already* reads from standard input.